# Why are there non-standard altitude callouts?

Tags: landing, altitude, airbus-a340, gpws, cockpit-alerts

I just saw a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/jz-VHeHkz6o?t=1m29s) with an A340 landing. There were the regular altitude callouts (1000, 500, etc.) until the callout "110". I was quite puzzled by this.

What are the conditions that the automatic callout would call "one hundred and ten" instead of one hundred?

Parenthetically, I'm almost certain - though I can't recall the details right now - that I've also heard a callout "seventy" in some other video, possibly with another plane type.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From the same channel and also an A340 at [4:26 in this video](https://youtu.be/cTJSv5ORr_w?t=266) the standard '100' can be heard.

The reason is a built-in timeout, if a certain time elapses between callouts—say due to non-standard [shallower] descent rate, perhaps due to high headwind for example—the current height is called out. In other words, you get to hear a callout at regular intervals.

From an A340 manual, here is the bit about the intermediate callouts:

[image]

---

Just a bit of history: one of the early TAWS systems (Mk II I believe) had a *rising tone* instead of the 100, 50, etc., you can [watch it here](https://youtu.be/hb6M9c-Bfes?t=337).

Note on terminology: those callouts are heights (radio), not altitudes (barometric).

Comment: What a great answer, cheers!