# What's the difference between the "100 above" and "100" GPWS above callout?

Tags: cockpit-alerts, gpws

Not all aircraft have both; this one does and can be heard at 1:12:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"100 above" refers to being 100 ft above the decision height, which is the height at which the pilot must initiate a missed approach if they do not have the required visual reference. The equivalent call on a Boeing is ‘approaching minimums’. The decision height or minimums will commonly be around 200 or 300 feet, but it is airport specific, so when you hear the "100 above" call, you are 100 ft above 200 or 300 ft (300 ft or 400 ft above the ground respectively) - or whatever the decision height is for your specific approach.

The "100" call means that you are 100 ft above the ground.

The audio clip in your video is a bit confusing, and probably not taken from a real flight. During a real approach, you would expect to first hear "100 above" followed by "minimums", since "minimums" is the call made at the decision height.

Comment: The audio clip in the video is a ground test of the GPWS and TCAS systems, which runs through all the calls.

Comment: Above ground or above runway elevation? That is, will you hear the “one hundred” call in the typical place when you are approaching a table-top runway with more than 100 ft drop closer than 1000 ft from the threshold?

Comment: @JanHudec Good question. For Boeing the 1000 and 500 callouts are based on barometric altitude above runway elevation and the rest is RA (see [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/71342/33692)). If I read the [A320 FCOM](https://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A320-Navigation.html) correctly, they are all based on RA.

Comment: @JanHudec Probably depends on whether you have inserted a decision height (DH) or decision altitude (DA)